# How to upload multiple files into a different table during registration?

Tags: php, file-upload, pdo

Good day everyone! I am using Dropzone Js to upload multiple files into a different table during registration. However I couldn't make the upload and registration to work at the same time. Most Dropzone tutorial code that I see online are using mysqli while I'm using PDO making it hard to integrate in to my code. I need to save the details of the user to a table while saving the files they uploaded to a different table together with the coopID as a foreign key.

I've tried using Dropzone Js to upload multiple files easily and I also use the php PDO function lastInsertID() to get the coopID of the user.

```
    <?php
include_once 'coop_functions.php';
session_start();

if(isset($_SESSION['loggedUser'])) {
    header("Location: coop_dashboard.php");
}


$errorList = NULL;
$firstName = "";
$lastName = "";
$coopName = "";
$userName = "";
$email = "";
$regNumber = "";
$coopNumber = "";
$address = "";
$contact = "";
$contact2 = "";
$city = "";
$status = "";
$coopType = "";
$photo = "";


// this code works but it doesn't save the coopID of the user
// if I put it inside if(isset($_POST['register'])) it doesn't work

if (! empty($_FILES)) {
    $imagePath = isset($_FILES["file"]["name"]) ? $_FILES["file"]["name"] : "Undefined";
    $targetPath = "uploads/";
    $imagePath = $targetPath . $imagePath;
    $tempFile = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];

    $targetFile = $targetPath . $_FILES['file']['name'];

    recordUpload($tempFile, $targetFile);
}
if (!empty($_GET["action"]) && $_GET["action"] == "save") {
    require_once ("dbconfig.php");

    print $sql = "INSERT INTO upload (photo) VALUES ('. $imagePath .')";
    mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
    $current_id = mysqli_insert_id($conn);
}


if(isset($_POST['register'])) {


    $firstName = $_POST['firstName'];
    $lastName = $_POST['lastName'];
    $coopName = $_POST['coopName'];
    $userName = $_POST['userName'];
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $regNumber = $_POST['regNumber'];
    $coopNumber = $_POST['coopNumber'];
    $address = $_POST['address'];
    $contact = $_POST['contact'];
    $contact2 = $_POST['contact2'];
    $city = $_POST['city'];
    $status = $_POST['status'];
    $coopType = $_POST['coopType'];


$imagePath = isset($_FILES["file"]["name"]) ? $_FILES["file"]["name"] : "Undefined";
    $targetPath = "uploads/";
    $imagePath = $targetPath . $imagePath;
    $tempFile = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];

        $targetFile = $targetPath . $_FILES['file']['name'];


    $errorList = registerValidateInput($firstName, $lastName, $coopName, $userName, $email, $regNumber, $coopNumber,
        $address, $contact, $contact2, $city, $status, $coopType, $_POST['password'], $_POST['confirmPassword']);


    if($errorList == NULL)
    {
        $errorList = registerVerifyInput($_POST['userName'], $_POST['email']);
        if($errorList == NULL)
        {
            $errorList = recordUpload($tempFile, $targetFile);
            if($errorList == NULL)
            {
                register(2, $_POST['firstName'], $_POST['lastName'], $_POST['coopName'], $_POST['userName'], $_POST['email'], $_POST['regNumber'], $_POST['coopNumber'], $_POST['address'],
                    $_POST['contact'], $_POST['contact2'], $_POST['city'], $_POST['status'], $_POST['coopType'], $_POST['password'], $targetFile);
                header("Location: coop_dashboard.php");
            }

        }
    }
}

?>
```

//I deleted the input tags to make the code short

```
<form class="login-form form-all" action="coop_register.php" method="post">

    <button type="submit" name="register" class="green-btn green-btn-form btn-login">Create </button>
</form>
<form name="frmImage" action="coop_register.php?action=save" class="dropzone">
</form>
```

//These are my functions it is located in a different file called coop_functions.php

```
function connect()
{
    global $server, $database, $dbusername, $dbpassword;
    try {
        $connection = new PDO("mysql:host=$server; dbname=$database", $dbusername, $dbpassword);
        $connection->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
        return $connection;
    } catch (PDOException $exception) {
        echo "Error encountered: " . $exception->getMessage();
        return NULL;
    }
}

function recordUpload($tempFile, $targetFile)
{

   $errorList = array();
    try {
        move_uploaded_file($tempFile, $targetFile);
    } catch(Exception $exception) {
        array_push($errorList, "Error: " . $exception -> getMessage());
    }
    if (!empty($errorList)) {
        return $errorList;
    } else {
        return NULL;
    }
}

function register($roleID, $firstName, $lastName, $coopName, $userName,  $email, $regNumber, $coopNumber, $address, $contact, $contact2, $city,
                  $status, $coopType, $password, $photo)
{
    try
    {
        $connection = connect();
        $stmt= $connection->prepare("INSERT INTO cooperative(roleID, firstName, lastName, 
        coopName, userName, email, regNumber, coopNumber, address, contact, contact2, city, status, coopType, password)
        VALUES (:roleID,:firstName, :lastName, :coopName, :userName, :email, :regNumber, :coopNumber, :address,
        :contact, :contact2, :city, :status, :coopType, :password)");
        $stmt->bindParam(":roleID", $roleID);
        $stmt->bindParam(":firstName", $firstName);
        $stmt->bindParam("lastName", $lastName);
        $stmt->bindParam(":coopName", $coopName);
        $stmt->bindParam(":userName", $userName);
        $stmt->bindParam(":email", $email);
        $stmt->bindParam("regNumber", $regNumber);
        $stmt->bindParam("coopNumber", $coopNumber);
        $stmt->bindParam(":address", $address);
        $stmt->bindParam(":contact", $contact);
        $stmt->bindParam(":contact2", $contact2);
        $stmt->bindParam(":city", $city);
        $stmt->bindParam(":status", $status);
        $stmt->bindParam(":coopType", $coopType);
        $hashedPassword = hash("sha256", $password);
        $stmt->bindParam(":password", $hashedPassword);
        $stmt->execute();

        $coopID = $connection->lastInsertID();
        $statement = $connection->prepare("INSERT INTO upload(coopID, photo) VALUES (:coopID, :photo)");
        $statement->bindParam(":coopID", $coopID);
        $statement->bindParam(":photo", $photo);
        $statement->execute();

        $coopID = $connection->lastInsertID();
        $detail = "$firstName $lastName registered into the system.";
        recordAudit($connection, $coopID, 1, $detail);
        recordUpload($connection, $coopID);
    }
    catch (PDOException $exception)
    {
        die("Error: " . $exception->getMessage());
    }

}
```

There is no error message it's just not working the way intend it. After registering either the coopID is save to the database but no upload files or files are uploaded but no coopID. I am beginner in PHP any help is appreciated thank you.

Comment: Can you show you code in the `connect();` function **Just change the password**

Comment: there is no password I'm using root.

Comment: Yea Ooops! Enough said. I would like to see why no errors are being seen, and the extra parameters that you may or may not have added to the connection process will tell me this. I only mentioned obfiscating the password as a curtacy

Comment: Okay I included the code for the connect();  function on top of the recordUpload function.